# While Numbers from 10 sum until result is 1000

Tags: c#, console, console-application

Hello my currenct code is doing sum on numbers after + including 10 I need it only after, now is doing like 10 + 10 = 20 then 20 +11 = 31 and etc which is wrong, when I change my i with 11 it adds 1 more interaction to the correct and makes the number more than 1000.

```
``  `
            int i = 10;
            int a = 10;

            while (a < 1000)
            {
                a += i++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
```

```
Tried to change the numbers to 11 which is correct but gives me 1 more interaction which I want to remove!
```

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand your question.. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Your while loop runs until `a` is equal or greater than 1000. Do you want to stop before it exceeds 1000? Maybe this is what you mean?

Comment: Exactly  this is what i want

Comment: @KlausGütter I have no idea why it is or greater than 1000 when I fo < only

Comment: Imaging that `a` is e.g. 999. Then you will add `i` and get to a value > 1000. Only then the loop condition is checked again and the loop is ternminated.

Comment: @TomS so when I change i to 11. It is correct but makes 1 more interaction which I want to remove and be only a < 1000

Comment: @KlausGütter I tried to make a<950 which works but its not correct as code

Answer (score 0):

sorry, do you mean to increment only by 10 ?, you can change `a += i++;` to `a += i;`

Comment: I mean when i make i 11 it works but it do 1 more interaction

Answer (score 0):

So you want to termionate the loop **before** `a` gets > 1000.
The easiest way is to calculate the new value but not yet assign it to `a`:

```
int i = 10;
int a = 10;

while (a < 1000)
{
    int newValue = a + i;
    if (newValue > 1000) break;
    i++;
    a = newValue;
}

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

**Alternative:** you could also modify the while condition. As you know you are going to add `i`, check if the result would be still <= 1000:

```
while (a + i <= 1000)
{
    a += i++;
}
```

**Alternative 2:** Another strategy proposed in @Slepcho's comment is to undo the last addition after the loop:

```
while (a <= 1000) 
{ 
    a += i++; 
}
a -= --i;
```

Comment: Is it possible with other way than if?

Comment: Of course, there are many ways, as always. What is it that you don't like?

Comment: That works but still cw 47 interactions instead 46

Comment: I'm lost now. Could you please formulate your requirements exactly?

Comment: I fixed it ```     
       int i = 11;
            int a = 10;

            while (a < 1000)
            {
                a += i++;
            }

            i -= 1;
            a -= i;

            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine(i);```

Comment: But this is wrong for `i = 10`. You will have to change to `a <= 1000`

Comment: welll works for me so whatever this is the solution i sent

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
            int i = 11;
            int a = 10;

            while (a < 1000)
            {
                a += i++;
            }

            i -= 1;
            a -= i;

            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: this is wrong for i = 10. You will have to change the condition to a <= 1000

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).